# Installing deb packages from a mounted CD

Tags: ubuntu, deb

I have mounted the Ubuntu server edition 10.10 on my server under a directory media/servercd. I would like to install some services from this (it is an ISO). I edited the sources.list file to say:

deb file:/media/servercd maverick main restricted and it's properly mounted but when I try apt-get install I get an error saying "unable to locate package" so what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

[This document](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptCdrom) appears to exactly address your question.

Comment: Yes.  Also, don't forget you'll need to run `apt-get update` to update the available packages database.